# Google Play. Can build be published only to new users?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app which is already published. I'd like to publish the next build only to new users so that old ones don't see the update.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility would be to publish it with a new package name, thus making it a new app.